# ACCESSING PERMISSIONS OPTION

Tags: admin-panel, reports, permissions

There is no `PERMISSION` in the drop down options if I click on `Reports` in the admin-panel .

Am i missing something?

Comment: what are you looking for ? Explain in details what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to disable the reports menu for certain user roles this can be achieved by navigating to..

> System > Permissions > Roles

Set the Role Resource to custom and then use Ctrl + F (Find) and search for 'Reports' you will see several options which you can leave unticked when creating your new role to not include this for the users.

- EDIT - Changed path to roles

Comment: Hello , Thanks for the response ,however my problem is ,when I go into SYSTEM ,  the drop down box does not show config. /permissions/ roles

Comment: @ALEX Sorry I put the incorrect path to permissions, it should be System > Permissions > Roles. If this is still not showing then double check you're logged in as a Magento administrator as it could be possible you don't have the correct permissions to view these paths.

Comment: Hello , Thanks for that , I thought that may be the problem , I own the site so I thought I should have access , we used a  company to build the site would they have access

Comment: @ALEX It is possible they created your user without full permissions. Perhaps get in touch with them to get your role changed to administrator. There may be alternative ways to change your user role but I'm afraid I don't have any experience myself in that.